# Offset a date by one month in R

Tags: r

I have a date, let's say July 7th, 2020.

```
my_date <- as.Date("2020/07/07")
```

I want to offset this date by one month. So it should return August 7th, 2020.

I tried `my_date + 30` but it doesn't work if the month has 30 or 31 days.

EDIT

I have to be precise in my question. What if the date is May 31, 2020? It should offset to June 30, 2020. Please, a help in base R is desirable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `%m+%` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
my_date <- as.Date("2020/07/07")
my_date %m+% months(1)
#[1] "2020-08-07"
```

`my_date + months(1)` also works in this case but it messes up calculation if it's last day of month.

```
my_date <- as.Date("2020/05/31")
my_date + months(1)
#[1] NA

my_date %m+% months(1)
#[1] "2020-06-30"
```

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, I have edited my question due to your concern on a date like May 31. Just a question, do you know if a base R solution is possible in this case?

Comment: I am not aware about a flawless and simple approach to do this in base R. I can think of method suggested by Jilber, or using `as.POSIXlt` and changing `mon` part from it Or using some regex. All these methods have their own drawbacks. Perhaps, you can write your own custom function using some `if`/`else` to test for various months if you don't want to use `lubridate` function.

Comment: I appreciate your time and answer Ronak, I think it's better to use `lubridate` and code faster. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `seq`

```
> my_date <- as.Date("2020/07/07")
> seq(my_date,length=2,by="months")[2]
[1] "2020-08-07"
```

Comment: `my_date <- as.Date("2020/05/31")`

Comment: Hello @Jilber Urbina, thank you for the answer, but I realized a flaw in my question, what if the date is May 31? I have edited my question above to be more clear.